# How to have parametrizable "methods" in Elm data-structures

Tags: data-structures, elm

I'm stuck refactoring a large data-structure in Elm. I know how I would implement this in OO languages, but have no experience in a functional setting. I can't express well what my problem is, because I can only frame it in OOP terms which don't apply. So I go by way of example, which is a simplified version of the module I'm refactoring.

Suppose I have this type:

```
type alias Book = { title : String, text : String }
```

and I have two Books:

```
englishBook = { title = "An English Book", text = "This book is an Eglish book." }
frenchBook = { title = "Un livre Francais", text = "Ce livre est un livre Francais." }
```

There is an associated `index` function to compute which words are in a `Book`:

```
index = String.words >> Set.fromList
```

Here's already my first problem. When `index` takes a String, the user of the module must know how to take the text from the book. Instead, my habits say that the function should do this for us. So `index` could behave like a method and take a `Book` as first argument: `index = .text >> String.words >> Set.fromList`. But that also feels weird.

That's not the end of it though, because the index generator should be parametrizable. Depending on the book, it should do different things. So I could add the index function like this:

```
englishBook = { title = "...", text = "...", index = englishIndex }
frenchBook = { title = "...", text = "...", index = frenchIndex }
```

now each book has the function to build its index. But still the caller has to supply the record when it wants the index:

```
wordsInEnglishBook = englishBook.index englishBook.text
```

which is not a nice solution to me because it burdens the caller with internals of the module. Well what if that part is encapsulated with a constructor?

```
book title text index = { title = title, text = text, index = \_ -> index text }
```

Now I've come full circle and have implemented a method. So **what is the idiomatic solution for this in Elm**?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your situation or your question. Certainly in the case where the `index` function is fixed, `index = .text >> String.words >> Set.fromList` looks like the perfect solution to me, and I'm not sure why you say it "feels weird". But when the index function varies (I presume quite considerably) from one `book` to another, I would just define a function like this: `wordsInBook book = book.index book`. Then you can just call `wordsInBook` on any `book` value and not need to care about the internals.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Seems like a perfectly good design to me. Consider making this an answer?

Comment: @oobalance I'd be happy to make it an answer if I was sure it fulfilled their needs. As I said, I found the question somewhat vague (even though I can see quite a bit of effort went into framing and asking it), so I'm not convinced I really understand it. Also I am new to Elm so I don't feel I can comment with any authority on best practices from a design point of view.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks I'll go with your suggestion and see how it works out in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom type to represent the language then pattern match on the language to perform your index.

```
type Language
    = English
    | French


type alias Book =
    { title : String
    , text : String
    , language : Language
    }


wordsInBook : Book -> Set String
wordsInBook { language, text } =
    case language of
        English ->
            doSomethingWithEnglish text

        French ->
            doSomethingWithFrench text
```

or

```
type Book
    = Book Language Data


type Language
    = English
    | French


type alias Data =
    { title : String
    , text : String
    }


wordsInBook : Book -> Set String
wordsInBook (Book language data) =
    case language of
        English ->
            doSomethingWithEnglish data

        French ->
            doSomethingWithFrench data
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I realize my example with the two books is misleading. In my case every book can have a different index, depending on what fits that book. There are almost as many ways to index as there are books. Sorry for the contrived example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @sba. Am I right in thinking you'll be writing a unique index function for almost every book that you add? If it's possible; breaking these index functions down into a finite set of smaller composable functions may allow for a simpler solution.

Comment: Yeah, for example the index function could be parameterized to use different stop-words for each book. Or it might have to account for special names in some.